# What is the emoticon ":hsugh:"?

Tags: meaning, emoticons

Some forums have this emoticon: *:hsugh:* that you could choose to post with your messages. The resulting graphic looks like this: [image]

What's the meaning of this emoticon? What emotion does it convey?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the meaning of emoticons, not English as such.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's either derived from "sigh", but spelled incorrectly (it does look like someone who's a little disappointed and maybe is going to sigh). The only other possible thing I can think of is that it's derived from "ugh", a word that is usually uses to express stronger negative emotions (horror, disgust) than this little icon seems to be feeling.

Comment: I have no problem with this question. It is about the English word or phrase for something. To me it is a translation question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about emoticons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so a quick google brought me to [this page](http://forum.feelslike98.com/misc.php?do=showsmilies).

*hsugh* breaks down into two parts: *hs* and *ugh*.

*hs* means "happy sad". This is the emoticon for that: [image: happy sad smiley]

*ugh* is a sort of feeling of confusion (I think, although it might be disgust, or both). This is the emoticon for that: [image: ugh smiley]

So merging them together you get hsugh, some kind of happy-sad feeling of confusion.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [cogsci.se] lol

Comment: One forum I'm on uses `:err:` for the second one.